# SQL Server incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Add_Student, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

when trying to run this SQL query:

```
CREATE proc [Add_Student](
    @stud_id varchar(5),
    @fname varchar(25),
    @lname varchar(25),
    @balance decimal = 0
)       
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO MyStudent(Student_ID, Fname, Lname, Acct_Bal)
        VAULES (@stud_id, @fname, @lname, @balance)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            Rollback Transaction
            Raiserror ('Unable to insert record.',16,1)
            return -1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            Commit Transaction
            Print 'Record Added Successfully!'
        END
    END
```

Comment: This is not a complete stored procedure definition - only the header - you need to write the actual **body** of the stored procedure next!

Comment: Why do you have "create proc" twice?  Is that a typo?

Comment: The doubled up `CREATE PROC` would explain that error

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo near ")":

```
INSERT INTO MyStudent(Student_ID, Fname, Lname, Acct_Bal)
VAULES (@stud_id, @fname, @lname, @balance)
```

It should be "VALUES" not "VAULES".