# Incorrect syntax near ','. when using Exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**Issue:** Incorrect syntax near ','. (Procedure spAddNewDataToHoldingTable, Line 71)

**Aim:** Insert data to Table (which I created via another stored procedure)

Thoughts: I've tried a few combinations of apostrophes and if I get the SQL to run then it means no apostrophe before the first value and therefor an error.

I hope one apostrophe in the wrong place is all it is.

IF I did not have a variable name I could run without EXEC but I also want to make it as secure.

**Code:**

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 

@sTableName varchar(50),
@sPMNUM varchar(8),
@sUPRN varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyDate Date,
@sVFMDISCIPLINE varchar(4) ,
@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT varchar(510) ,
@sWorkOrder varchar(510) ,
@sNextSurveyDue  Date ,
@sRiskCategory varchar(510) ,
@sDocURL varchar(MAX) ,
@sDocLinks varchar(MAX) ,
@sVINCIRISKLevel varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionWO varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionDate date,
@sComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRISKNUM varchar(510) ,
@sRISKOWNER varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyorsComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRecommendations varchar(510) ,
@sStatusOfIssue int ,
@sClientContract varchar(12) ,
@sJPNUM varchar(12)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sTablename_ AS varchar(max)

SET @sTablename_ = LTRIM(RTRIM(@sTableName))

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @sTablename_  + '
(
PMNUM,
UPRN,
VFMDISPLINE,
VFMDISPLINEELEMENT,
WorkOrder,
RiskCategory,
DocURL,
DocLinks,
VINCIRISKLevel,
RemedialActionWO,
Comments,
RISKNUM,
RISKOWNER,
SurveyorsComments,
Recommendation,
StatusOfIssue,
ClientContract,
JPNUM,
RemedialActionDate  ,
SurveyDate ,
NextSurveyDate  
)

VALUES

('''

+ ''' + QUOTENAME(@sPMNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sUPRN) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINE) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sWorkOrder) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRiskCategory) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocURL) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocLinks) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVINCIRISKLevel) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionWO) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKOWNER) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyorsComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRecommendations) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sStatusOfIssue + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sClientContract) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sJPNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sNextSurveyDue) + '''
+ ''')'''

EXEC (@sql)

END
```

**Ref:**

[SQL Server incorrect syntax near ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135438/sql-server-incorrect-syntax-near?rq=1)
[Incorrect syntax near '(' and near '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675954/incorrect-syntax-near-and-near)

Comment: Your values list contains commas that are not part of the SQL string (they are not properly quoted)

Comment: replace `EXEC (@sql)` by `SELECT (@sql)` or `print @sql`

Comment: That the only thing that is dynamic is your table name, indicates you're "doing it wrong". Youve got dynamic tables being created (with the same columns) rather than a proper database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `quotename()` on all of those, it just wraps them in square brackets.

Don't forget to `convert()` your `date` datatypes to `varchar`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 

@sTableName varchar(50),
@sPMNUM varchar(8),
@sUPRN varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyDate Date,
@sVFMDISCIPLINE varchar(4) ,
@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT varchar(510) ,
@sWorkOrder varchar(510) ,
@sNextSurveyDue  Date ,
@sRiskCategory varchar(510) ,
@sDocURL varchar(MAX) ,
@sDocLinks varchar(MAX) ,
@sVINCIRISKLevel varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionWO varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionDate date,
@sComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRISKNUM varchar(510) ,
@sRISKOWNER varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyorsComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRecommendations varchar(510) ,
@sStatusOfIssue int ,
@sClientContract varchar(12) ,
@sJPNUM varchar(12)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sTablename_ AS varchar(max)

SET @sTablename_ = LTRIM(RTRIM(@sTableName))

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @sTablename_  + '
(
PMNUM,
UPRN,
VFMDISPLINE,
VFMDISPLINEELEMENT,
WorkOrder,
RiskCategory,
DocURL,
DocLinks,
VINCIRISKLevel,
RemedialActionWO,
Comments,
RISKNUM,
RISKOWNER,
SurveyorsComments,
Recommendation,
StatusOfIssue,
ClientContract,
JPNUM,
RemedialActionDate  ,
SurveyDate ,
NextSurveyDate  
)

VALUES

('

+   '''' + @sPMNUM                + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sUPRN                 + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sVFMDISCIPLINE        + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sWorkOrder            + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sRiskCategory         + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sDocURL               + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sDocLinks             + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sVINCIRISKLevel       + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sRemedialActionWO     + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sComments             + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sRISKNUM              + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sRISKOWNER            + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sSurveyorsComments    + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sRecommendations      + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sStatusOfIssue        + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sClientContract       + ''''
+ ', ''' + @sJPNUM                + ''''
+ ', ''' + convert(varchar(10),@sRemedialActionDate,120)+ ''''
+ ', ''' + convert(varchar(10),@sSurveyDate,120)        + ''''
+ ', ''' + convert(varchar(10),@sNextSurveyDue,120)     + ''''
+ ');'

EXEC (@sql)
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You added another '''

here is updated one

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 

@sTableName varchar(50),
@sPMNUM varchar(8),
@sUPRN varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyDate Date,
@sVFMDISCIPLINE varchar(4) ,
@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT varchar(510) ,
@sWorkOrder varchar(510) ,
@sNextSurveyDue  Date ,
@sRiskCategory varchar(510) ,
@sDocURL varchar(MAX) ,
@sDocLinks varchar(MAX) ,
@sVINCIRISKLevel varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionWO varchar(510) ,
@sRemedialActionDate date,
@sComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRISKNUM varchar(510) ,
@sRISKOWNER varchar(510) ,
@sSurveyorsComments varchar(MAX) ,
@sRecommendations varchar(510) ,
@sStatusOfIssue int ,
@sClientContract varchar(12) ,
@sJPNUM varchar(12)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sTablename_ AS varchar(max)

SET @sTablename_ = LTRIM(RTRIM(@sTableName))

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @sTablename_  + '
(
PMNUM,
UPRN,
VFMDISPLINE,
VFMDISPLINEELEMENT,
WorkOrder,
RiskCategory,
DocURL,
DocLinks,
VINCIRISKLevel,
RemedialActionWO,
Comments,
RISKNUM,
RISKOWNER,
SurveyorsComments,
Recommendation,
StatusOfIssue,
ClientContract,
JPNUM,
RemedialActionDate  ,
SurveyDate ,
NextSurveyDate  
)

VALUES

(''' + QUOTENAME(@sPMNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sUPRN) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINE) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sWorkOrder) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRiskCategory) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocURL) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocLinks) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVINCIRISKLevel) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionWO) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKOWNER) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyorsComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRecommendations) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sStatusOfIssue) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sClientContract) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sJPNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sNextSurveyDue) + ''')'

EXEC (@sql)

END
```

Comment: Check the closing `)` - I think that also has too many quotes

Answer (score 0):

To escape a single quote you need to double it up. 
Therefore ''', ''' will be returned as ','

So, your code should look like this:

```
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @sTablename_  + '
(
PMNUM,
UPRN,
VFMDISPLINE,
VFMDISPLINEELEMENT,
WorkOrder,
RiskCategory,
DocURL,
DocLinks,
VINCIRISKLevel,
RemedialActionWO,
Comments,
RISKNUM,
RISKOWNER,
SurveyorsComments,
Recommendation,
StatusOfIssue,
ClientContract,
JPNUM,
RemedialActionDate  ,
SurveyDate ,
NextSurveyDate  
)

VALUES

(
''' + QUOTENAME(@sPMNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sUPRN) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINE) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sWorkOrder) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRiskCategory) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocURL) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sDocLinks) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sVINCIRISKLevel) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionWO) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRISKOWNER) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyorsComments) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRecommendations) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sStatusOfIssue) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sClientContract) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sJPNUM) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sRemedialActionDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sSurveyDate) + '''
, ''' + QUOTENAME(@sNextSurveyDue) + ''')'
```

Comment: Why was my answer voted down? It resolves the OP's issue regarding the incorrect syntax in the given query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using dynamic sql here, you should instead be fixing the design that causes you have to need multiple tables all with the exact same schema. However, if you are going to stick with this you need to use parameters in your dynamic sql instead of trying to fight single quotes all over the place. And simply adding a set of double single quotes is only going to delay the problems with this. Here is how you can do this with dynamic sql and parameterize all the values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 
(
    @sTableName varchar(50),
    @sPMNUM varchar(8),
    @sUPRN varchar(510) ,
    @sSurveyDate Date,
    @sVFMDISCIPLINE varchar(4) ,
    @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT varchar(510) ,
    @sWorkOrder varchar(510) ,
    @sNextSurveyDue Date ,
    @sRiskCategory varchar(510) ,
    @sDocURL varchar(MAX) ,
    @sDocLinks varchar(MAX) ,
    @sVINCIRISKLevel varchar(510) ,
    @sRemedialActionWO varchar(510) ,
    @sRemedialActionDate date,
    @sComments varchar(MAX) ,
    @sRISKNUM varchar(510) ,
    @sRISKOWNER varchar(510) ,
    @sSurveyorsComments varchar(MAX) ,
    @sRecommendations varchar(510) ,
    @sStatusOfIssue int ,
    @sClientContract varchar(12) ,
    @sJPNUM varchar(12)
) AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

    SET @sql = N'
    INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM(@sTableName)))  + '
    (
        PMNUM
        , UPRN
        , VFMDISPLINE
        , VFMDISPLINEELEMENT
        , WorkOrder
        , RiskCategory
        , DocURL
        , DocLinks
        , VINCIRISKLevel
        , RemedialActionWO
        , Comments
        , RISKNUM
        , RISKOWNER
        , SurveyorsComments
        , Recommendation
        , StatusOfIssue
        , ClientContract
        , JPNUM
        , RemedialActionDate
        , SurveyDate
        , NextSurveyDate  
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @sPMNUM
        , @sUPRN
        , @sVFMDISCIPLINE
        , @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT
        , @sWorkOrder
        , @sRiskCategory
        , @sDocURL
        , @sDocLinks
        , @sVINCIRISKLevel
        , @sRemedialActionWO
        , @sComments
        , @sRISKNUM
        , @sRISKOWNER
        , @sSurveyorsComments
        , @sRecommendations
        , @sStatusOfIssue
        , @sClientContract
        , @sJPNUM
        , @sRemedialActionDate
        , @sSurveyDate
        , @sNextSurveyDue
    )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        , N'@sPMNUM varchar(8)
            , @sUPRN varchar(510)
            , @sVFMDISCIPLINE varchar(4)
            , @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT varchar(510)
            , @sWorkOrder varchar(510)
            , @sRiskCategory varchar(510)
            , @sDocURL varchar(MAX)
            , @sDocLinks varchar(MAX)
            , @sVINCIRISKLevel varchar(510)
            , @sRemedialActionWO varchar(510)
            , @sComments varchar(MAX)
            , @sRISKNUM varchar(510)
            , @sRISKOWNER varchar(510)
            , @sSurveyorsComments varchar(MAX)
            , @sRecommendations varchar(510)
            , @sStatusOfIssue int
            , @sClientContract varchar(12)
            , @sJPNUM varchar(12)
            , @sRemedialActionDate varchar(10)
            , @sSurveyDate varchar(10)
            , @sNextSurveyDue varchar(10)'
        , @sPMNUM = @sPMNUM
        , @sUPRN = @sUPRN
        , @sVFMDISCIPLINE = @sVFMDISCIPLINE
        , @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT = @sVFMDISCIPLINEELEMENT
        , @sWorkOrder = @sWorkOrder
        , @sRiskCategory = @sRiskCategory
        , @sDocURL = @sDocURL
        , @sDocLinks = @sDocLinks
        , @sVINCIRISKLevel = @sVINCIRISKLevel
        , @sRemedialActionWO = @sRemedialActionWO
        , @sComments = @sComments
        , @sRISKNUM = @sRISKNUM
        , @sRISKOWNER = @sRISKOWNER
        , @sSurveyorsComments = @sSurveyorsComments
        , @sRecommendations = @sRecommendations
        , @sStatusOfIssue = @sStatusOfIssue
        , @sClientContract = @sClientContract
        , @sJPNUM = @sJPNUM
        , @sRemedialActionDate = @sRemedialActionDate
        , @sSurveyDate = @sSurveyDate
        , @sNextSurveyDue = @sNextSurveyDue     
END;
```